# What constitutes as padding in a union?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11

I'm trying to interpret the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) regarding static (and thread-local) initialisation of a union when not explicitly initialised.

Section 6.7.9 10 (pg 139) states the following:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

Supposing we're on an amd64 architecture, given the following statement:

```
static union { uint32_t x; uint16_t y[3]; } u;
```

**Can `u.y[2]` contain non-zero values or is it initialised to zero because it is regarded as padding?**

I've scoured the C11 standard but there is little to no explanation as to what constitutes as padding in a union. In the [C99 standard (pg 126)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) padding isn't mentioned, so in that case `u.y[2]` can be non-zero.

Comment: **Do you mean `u.y[3]`?** My understanding is that if the union need some padding, it will be initialized to 0. Assuming that u require 4 bytes alignment on your architecture and y[3] is 6 bytes and require 2 bytes alignment, then final alignment need to be a multiple of 8 and thus you would have a 2 bytes padding (essentially at u.y[3]).which will be 0.

Comment: @PSkocik: I was wrong, a union can have padding at the end, outside any member, when one member is an array with less-strict alignment that does not fill out the space required for the more-strict alignment of another member (and the array is also larger than the other member, so that other member does not itself fill the required space).

Comment: The only explicit mention in the standard of padding in a union itself (rather than in its members) is in the padding which may be at the end, as would correspond to `u.y[3]` in the example in the question. As a consumer of a C implementation, I would have to interpret the passage this question asks about as telling me that that trailing padding is initialized to zero and not telling me that the bytes in `y` and not in `x` (hence `u.y[2]`) are initialized to zero. As an implementation developer, I might take the precaution of initializing all bytes to zero.

Answer (score 5):

The extra space used by `y` that isn't used by `x` is *not* considered padding.  Section 6.7.2.1p17 of the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding "Structure and union specifiers" states:

> There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union

The bytes used by `y` in your example that are not used by `x` are still named, and are therefore not padding.

Your example most likely *does* have this unnamed padding, since the largest member takes up 6 bytes but one of the members is a `uint32_t` which typically requires 4 byte alignment.  In fact, on gcc 4.8.5 the size of this union is 8 bytes.  So the memory layout of this union looks like this:

```
            -----  --|       ---|
         0  | 0 |    |          |
            -----    |          |-- y[0]
         1  | 0 |    |          |
            -----    |-- x   ---|
         2  | 0 |    |          |            
            -----    |          |-- y[1]
         3  | 0 |    |          |
            -----  --|       ---|
         4  | 0 |               |
            -----               |-- y[2]
         5  | 0 |               |
            -----            ---|
         6  | 0 |  -- padding
            -----
         7  | 0 |  -- padding
            -----
```

So going by a strict reading of the standard, for a static instance of this union without an explicit initializer:

- Bytes 0 - 3, corresponding to `x` (i.e. the first named member), are initialized to 0 resulting in `x` being 0.
- Bytes 4 - 5, corresponding to y[2], remain **uninitialized** and have **indeterminate values**.
- Bytes 6 - 7, corresponding to padding, are initialized to 0.

I tested this on gcc 4.8.5, clang 3.3, and MSVC 2015, and all of them set **all** bytes to 0 under various optimization settings.  However, going by a strict reading of the standard the behavior is not guaranteed, so it's still possible that a different optimization setting of these compilers, different versions of them, or different compilers altogether may do something different.

From a pragmatic standpoint, it would make sense for a compiler to simply set all bytes of a static object to 0 to satisfy this requirement.  This is assuming of course that no integer types have padding, floating point types are IEEE754, and NULL pointers have the numerical value of 0.  On most systems that most people are likely to come across, this will be the case.  Systems where this is not the case might be more likely to leave these bytes set to something other than 0.  So again, while these bytes *might* be set to 0, there is no guarantee.

An important point to keep in mind is that a union can only store one member at a time as per 6.7.2.1p16:

> The  size  of  a  union  is  sufficient  to  contain  the  largest  of  its  members.  **The  value  of  at
>   most  one  of  the  members  can  be  stored  in  a  union  object  at  any  time.**   A  pointer  to  a
>   union  object,  suitably  converted,  points  to  each  of  its  members  (or  if  a  member  is  a  bit-
>   field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.

So if a `union` with static storage duration is uninitialized, it is only safe to access the *first* member since that is the one which was implicitly initialized.

The only exception to this is if the union contains structures with a common set of initial members, in which case you can access any of the common elements of the inner structs.  This is detailed in section 6.5.2.3p6:

> One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: if a union contains
>   several  structures  that  share  a  common  initial  sequence  (see  below),  and  if  the  union
>   object  currently  contains  one  of  these  structures,  it  is  permitted  to  inspect  the  common
>   initial part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the completed type of the union
>   is  visible.   Two  structures  share  a
>   common  initial  sequence
>   if  corresponding  members
>   have compatible types (and, for bit-fields, the same widths) for a sequence of one or more
>   initial members.

Comment: Another reason the union's bytes might be initially all zeroes on a typical real life system: when an object of static storage duration is valid to initialize with all zero bytes (and on most common systems, this will include pointer and floating types, not just integral), it would likely be placed in a "BSS" data segment. (Not sure about thread duration.)

Answer (score 0):

*`Can u.y[2] contain non-zero values or is it initialised to zero because it is regarded as padding?`*

`u.y[2]` is not regarded as padding. It is an element of array `y` which is a member of union `u`.

The union is only as big as necessary to hold its largest member (additional unnamed **trailing padding** may also be added for the purpose of [alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)).

From C Standard#6.7.2.1p17

> 17 There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union.

The largest member of union `u` is `uint16_t y[3];`. So, if there is any padding in union `u` then it will be after `uint16_t y[3];` member <sup>1)</sup>.

As per the C11 Standard, the union object that has static or thread storage duration and is not initialized explicitly the compiler should initialize the first named member (recursively) and any padding to zero bits. Hence, you should not make any assumption about `u.y[2]` value because the compiler will only initialize **first named member** of union<sup>2)</sup>, which is `uint32_t x` in your example, and any padding to zero bits (#6.7.9p10).

C Standard do not mention anything about the Data segment (initialized/uninitialized), Stack, Heap etc. These all are architecture/platform specific. For the object initialization, the C Standards only specify what to be initialize to `0` and what not and it does not specify which storage duration object go in which segment. The Standard specification are for compilers and a good compiler is expected to follow them. Typically, the `0` initialized static data goes in .BSS (Block Started by Symbol), non `0` initialized data goes in .DATA(Data Segment). So, you may find `u.y[2]` value `0` but that may not always be the case.

---

**1)** Every modern compiler will automatically use data structure padding depending on architecture. Some compilers even support the warning flag `-Wpadded` which generates helpful warnings about structure padding. These warnings help the programmer take manual care in case a more efficient data structure layout is desired.

> -Wpadded
>
> Warn if padding is included in a structure, either to align an element of the structure or to align the whole structure. Sometimes when this happens it is possible to rearrange the fields of the structure to reduce the padding and so make the structure smaller.

So, if your compiler supports warning flag `-Wpadded`, try compiling your code with it. That will help you in understanding the padding included by the compiler.

For e.g.

```
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() {
        static union { uint32_t x; uint16_t y[3]; } u;
}
```

Lets compile this with `-Wpadded` option. My compiler is `clang` version `clang-1000.10.44.4`

```
# clang -Wpadded p.c

p.c:4:16: warning: padding size of 'union (anonymous at p.c:4:16)' with 2 bytes to alignment boundary [-Wpadded]
        static union { uint32_t x; uint16_t y[3]; } u;
               ^
1 warning generated.
```

**2)** A point to note - if you explicitly initialize an union object, unless its a designated initialization, then also the **first member** of union will be initialized (C11 Standard#6.7.9p17).

Answer (score -1):

If the storage is automatic it may contain any value as it is not initialized.
If the storage is static it will initialized to zeroes.

Padding does not affect your union as it something which not belongs to any members of the structure or union.

For example if in your implementation data is padded to the 8 bytes boundary no padding will be added at all. There will be a 2 bytes gap between this union and the next object.

Comment: *"For example if in your implementation data is padded to the 8 bytes boundary no padding will be added at all. There will be a 2 bytes gap between this union and the next object."* - that is simply not true. The size of the union instance will be `8` in the case you cited. [See it live](https://ideone.com/doE0Qo). Padding is accounted for as part of the instance; not shoved in between them in some void. So either your statement isn't accurate or it wasn't communicated accurately and needs some polish.

Comment: @WhozCraig but it is not the padding in the standard sense. This one is left up to implementation. https://ideone.com/krfqGr